# Line breaking a logical symbol

Tags: python, line

I'm relatively new to python and don't quite understand what's going on here. I have the following code:

```
if cell.location != (always_empty_location
                     and random.random() < self.settings['OBSTACLE_RATIO']):
```

And it's broken, but if I remove the parenthesis and do a simple

```
and \
```

on the first line, it works. I can't seem to find a solid explanation of how python treats scenario's like this. Everything online suggests this should work.

Comment: Define "*it's broken*".

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: @melpomene - My tests go crazy, I'm getting a completely different behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with line breaks, it's just that

```
if a != b and c < d:
```

is very different from

```
if a != (b and c < d):
```

The first condition parses as `(a != b) and (c < d)` whereas the second condition parses as `a != (b and (c < d))`.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, you can only do multi-line conditionals if you wrap it in paren or if you use `\`.

So this works:

```
if foo == 1 and \
     bar == 2:
   do_something()
```

And this will work:

```
if (foo == 1 and
      bar == 2):
    do_something()
```

What you did, however, was putting a parenthesis around half of a condition!

```
if foo == (1
       and bar == 2):
    do_something()
```

So what is happening here is that it's evaluating `(1 and bar == 2)`, and then testing `foo` for that value. If `foo == True` then that would work. But if `foo == False` and `bar != 2`, then it'll pass.